# Using Rspec/Capybara, how erase 'browser' session cookie after visiting form (to simulate common cause of CSRF errors)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cookies, rspec, capybara

One of the form pages on our website is showing, occasionally, inconsistently, a fair number of ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken errors.

Viewing the logs we can see this occurs when:

a) user visits form (works)
b) clicks an option (works)
c) clicks another option **DAYS later** (causes CSRF error)

We believe the issue is that after (b) the user quits their browser, which erases session cookies, then when they re-open their browser if they have "reopen pages" enabled on their browser it re-displays the page, but there is no session and therefore the expected CSRF token is missing from their session.

We've added some code to handle that particular CSRF error with a custom error message.

We'd like to TEST the new code in rspec by simulating the same sequence of events.

That requires a way to erase Capybara's session for that user, simulating what happens if browser is closed then reopens:

```
visit form_url
click_button button_a
?? erase session cookie, with page object still 'open', so form object still exists??
click_button button_b
```

Using `reset_session!` wipes the page object too.

In an Rspec spec, how can we erase/invalidate the "browser" session cookie so when we click another button on the form, a Rails CSRF error will be triggered?

Comment: You can’t in a cross driver/browser compatible way - so what driver and browser are you testing with?

Comment: none, just the default Capybara::DSL

Comment: Whatever you’re doing you’re using a driver, it could be rack_test, selenium,etc

Comment: [`session.reset!`](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/Capybara%2FSession:reset!) YMMV across drivers / browsers though as noted by @ThomasWalpole

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a simple way to do this that involves making a request to your Rails backend. The high level is that you expose a route and a controller action to test mode that you do not expose in any other environment.

Make the reqeust to this endpoint in the specific situation you want to clear the session cookie.

In the controller action, you clear the session cookie and and set this so that the request you have just made is not going to set a new session

```
# config/routes.rb
get 'clear-session', :to => 'application#__clear_session' if Rails.env.test?
```

and

```
# controllers/application.rb

if Rails.env.test?
  def __clear_session
    request.session_options[:skip] = true
    cookies['__yourapp_session'] = { :value => '', :expires => Time.at(0) }
  end
end
```